# Tool for productive diagram editing

Tags: diagram, vector-graphics

For my project, I have a set of hand-made diagrams that have grown in size and complexity since I created them in [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/). Now it is hardly manageable, so I tried different tools to increase my productivity. Surprisingly, I've failed to find the right functionality even in other software, which brought me here :).

What I need

- vector graphic
- free software, at least for academy
- any OS or web
- template/class system

The template system is what is missing in all tools I've tried (listed below):

- I want to be able to edit all objects belonging to some template/class without selecting them every time.
- At the same time, I need to move them around independently, so the grouping functionality is not what I'm looking for.
- Finally, I need to edit the text description inside the object independently for each object, while editing the text style for all objects at once. This is not possible with the Inscape clone functionality.

Software I've tried:

- [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/)
- google drawings
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)
- [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)

Answer (score 0):

I'd post this as a comment, but I don't seem to have enough reputation yet.

It sounds like you are actually looking for a [UML (Unified Modeling Language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagramming tool.

There are many out there, but it's been a while since I've used any free ones.  The one I use is [MS Visio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/visio/microsoft-visio-plans-and-pricing-compare-visio-options?ef_id=3a8b20f7c350135a803e43d77d3c30c1%3aG%3as&OCID=AIDcmmwf9kwzdj_SEM_3a8b20f7c350135a803e43d77d3c30c1%3aG%3as&lnkd=Bing_O365SMB_Brand&msclkid=3a8b20f7c350135a803e43d77d3c30c1&activetab=tabs:primaryr2), but I think the latest version probably has similar problems to what you are describing (and also it's not free, not even close, but maybe there's an academic version that your school has a license for?).  For what it's worth, it looks like the [yEd uml editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/ydoc) might be better at this.

Comment: Actually, my diagrams are not related to software development and they should be more illustrative than formal.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by template/class system.  Sounds like what you need is some sort of CSS layer on top of a typical vector tool, so you can customize what each text-box looks like as a "class/template/stamp", while each one would have it's own contents.